# JTextArea not working in multithreading - java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jtextarea

I have a code that updates the `JTextArea` in `run()` method.

But when `run` method executes the `append()` method is not executed.

It prints the currect value of `incomingMessage` variable but not gets append to the `JTextArea`.

```
public void run()
{

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            if(serverSocketMessage==null)
            {
                serverSocketMessage = new ServerSocket(Constants.INCOMING_MESSAGE_PORT);
            }
            System.out.println("Listening to incoming messages");

            ObjectInputStream objectInputSender;
            String incomingMessage = null;

            serverMessage = serverSocketMessage.accept();
            objectInputSender = new ObjectInputStream(serverMessage.getInputStream());
            Object objectMessage = objectInputSender.readObject();
            if (objectMessage instanceof String)
            {
                incomingMessage = objectMessage.toString();
                System.out.println("\nMessage\n"+incomingMessage);
                if(incomingMessage!= null)
                {
                    chatingJTextArea.append(incomingMessage);
                    System.out.println("Not null");
                }

                chatingJTextArea.append("\n");
                chatingJTextArea.append(incomingMessage);



            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: JTextArea's append method is an exception to the thread safety rule in Swing. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append(java.lang.String) According to the docs, you can append to a JTextArea from other threads.

Comment: @Bill they removed that comment in the JDK7 javadoc. And from my own experience, it wasn't that thread safe in earlier JDKs either

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 4):

Try invoking append in the `EDT`

```
private void addMessage(final String message) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            chatingJTextArea.append(message);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: +1 - and since there are more places, best wrap this into a custom method. You may have to make the method parameter incomingMessage `final` for this to compile...

Comment: @Reimeus i tried by calling addMessage(incomingMessage) in the if condition  but it is not working

Comment: @Kundan Are you sure addMessage is being invoked? I.e. is the type returned by `readObject` actually a String? `readObject` is typically used to read binary data...

Comment: @Reimeus  yes yes its invoking. I tried by printing the data of addMessage into that method and readObject is a string.

Comment: @Kundan post the code as an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so we can see the complete picture

Answer (score -1):

A solution would be to implement the processing using a SwingWorker. The doInBackground method would implement the processing and you would invoke the publish method with the String to be appended as the argument. Your SwingWorker would then override the process method to take a String argument and append it to the text area.

*I don't have enough privilege to make this a comment but I removed the thing you said is wrong.*

Comment: if(incomingMessage!= null)
     {
      //chatingJTextArea.append(incomingMessage);
      System.out.println("in function value"+incomingMessage);
      addMessage(incomingMessage);
      System.out.println("Not null");
     }

Comment: -1 for the update(jTextArea.getGraphics()). Swing components will automatically repaint themselves when a property is changed. If for some reason you need to repaint a component then you would use the `repaint()` method.